# What permaculture crops should I grow together in USDA zone 4a?

Tags: planting, permaculture, design

I'm trying to work on building a permaculture garden, and was wondering what I should plant in USDA zone 4A.

Ideally I'm looking for a list of each bed with crop combinations to have them help each other.

Comment: This question will be closed as too broad unless you provide more details such as your growing zone, urban/rural, size of property, goals and budgets

Comment: http://www.permaculture.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Permaculture-Techniques.pdf

Comment: Not much help, it's just general advice. I'm looking for more of a "wiki answer"

Comment: Permaculture can be practiced around the world to different degrees and with different resources.  Success lies with local practices and plants that work.  This is still too broad.

Comment: I agree that this is way too broad. There isn't a finite list of permaculture plants. Permaculture is all about doing what works in your particular environment and with your particular needs. The number of plants you can use to meet your goals is nearly endless. It would be better if you asked about a particular problem you wanted to solve with permaculture and we could work from there. Also, initially when you wrote your post, I thought you meant permaculture zones, not USDA zones. We could give recommendations for different permie zones in your USDA zone.

Comment: How do we submit questions to the wiki?

Comment: Did the revision help at all?